# Upsert query not working with null value. how to update with null value in constraints?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I am using pgsql upsert query on conflict based on three column combination. Here one column can be null or not and other two columns will always contain the value. Upsert query working(updating values) when all three columns have values if another column which can be null doesn't have values so it is inserting record instead of updating.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."plan_line_items" (
    "plan_id" int4 NOT NULL
    "module_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "sub_module_id" int4,
    "created_date" timestamptz(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "modified_date" timestamptz(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "created_by" int4 NOT NULL,
    "modified_by" int4 NOT NULL,
    "is_active" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
);

INSERT INTO plan_line_items1 ( plan_id,module_id, sub_module_id, created_by, modified_by, modified_date )
VALUES ( '1', '1', '1', '36', '36', 'now()' ),
( '1', '2', null, '36', '36', 'now()' ) ON CONFLICT ( 
plan_id,module_id,sub_module_id ) DO UPDATE SET modified_by = EXCLUDED.modified_by,
modified_date = EXCLUDED.modified_date
```

When I tried this query first time its inserting record. after that when I tried the second time it is updating only that record which has all plan_id,module_id,sub_module_id with 1. not updating that record which is already inserted with the third null value( '1', '2', null, '36', '36', 'now()' ). I tried many things but did not found any way to do this. I want to update that record when executing this query second time instead of the insert.
If anybody has a solution please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're somewhat misinterpreting what `NULL` means here within the context of your unique constraint (which I assume you have in place even though it is not present in your DDL).

`sub_module_id` with a `NULL` value does not mean "this `plan_line_item` does not have a `sub_module_id`" it means "we do not know whether this `plan_line_item` has a `sub_module_id`". This is why it is not working as expected in your unique constraint.

I would suggest changing the data type of the `sub_module_id` column to :

```
sub_module_id int4 not null default 0
```

...and then inserting a value of `0` instead of `NULL` for those `plan_line_item` rows that have no `sub_module_id`. Hence :

```
CREATE TABLE regt.plan_line_items (
    plan_id int4 NOT null,
    module_id int4 NOT NULL,
    sub_module_id int4 not null default 0,
    created_date timestamptz(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    modified_date timestamptz(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    created_by int4 NOT NULL,
    modified_by int4 NOT NULL,
    is_active bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    unique (plan_id,module_id,sub_module_id)
);

INSERT INTO regt.plan_line_items ( plan_id,module_id, sub_module_id, created_by, modified_by, modified_date )
VALUES ( '1', '1', '1', '36', '36', 'now()' ),
( '1', '2', '0', '36', '36', 'now()' ) ON CONFLICT ( 
plan_id,module_id,sub_module_id ) DO UPDATE SET modified_by = EXCLUDED.modified_by,
modified_date = EXCLUDED.modified_date;
```

Or, to put it another way : `NULL` != `NULL`

Comment: Ok, thank you for help Tom, We can use this way but I have done other things based on if sub_module_id is null. if I use this way then I will have to change those things which I have done based on if sub_module_id is null. Is there any another way to do this?

Comment: `NULL <> NULL` is *not* true (but it isn't false either).